# Benefits of Java in education?

Tags: java, language-design

I hope this isn't too off-topic and/or opinion based.

I'm looking for examples and reasons why Java is an acceptable language for education purposes.

Here's why: I learned programming on my own in C at the age of about 15. In school we used Pascal (which I think is quite OK, especially in educational context). In University, Java was used and I was disgusted. Examples:

Verbosity:

```
RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
     RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setRenderingHints(rh);
```

---

Listener classes instead of functions.

---

No overloading (resulting in ugly `.equals()` and `.get()` instead of `==` and `[]`).

---

When I was able to pick a programming language on my own again, I chose Python and everything "felt just right".

Now the problem is that I'm going to become a teacher for computer science in german secondary schools (grade 5-13), where I will be forced to teach Java.

So I'm looking for the *pretty parts* of Java. What is especially easy/readable/... to implement in Java?

Preferably in an educational context, but also from a professional programmer's point of view.

Comment: I think the strongest points form java are: A lot of tools as e.g. IDS, and it is used a lot in jobs and research.

Comment: I suspect imperative languages in general are awful from an educational standpoint. They have weak type systems and encourage unnecessary mutation, which destroys your ability to use parallelism and reason *rigorously* about non-trivial code. Mainstream OOP languages are even worse, because inheritance is bad. Dynamic typing is also a trap. The main benefit to learning Java is that you'll have to use it in the real world; however, learning Java can come later, after the introductory courses. Further reading: http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/intro-curriculum-update/

Comment: There is no "battle". If you code in a relatively side-effect-free manner - which is generally considered a good thing even among OOP programmers - you're already well over halfway there to "declarative" programming.

Comment: @Jasper I think it's important to understand that everyone's definition of "pretty" will vary depending on a variety of things (personal history, level of proficiency, types of projects attempted).  Without keeping that in mind, I doubt you'll be satisfied with any answer.  As a sidenote, I'm slightly curious how it is that you were happy with both Pascal as well as Python, since they  are nothing alike (IMHO).

Comment: @Doval Put down the torch, asbestos suits are pretty uncomfortable. (Read: Evangelism is off topic here and may cause flame wars.)

Comment: @Jasper probably you want to take a look at JVM based languages like groovy or scala.

Comment: Java: The Good Parts - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596803742.do

Comment: This is an opinion, not an answer. The [reasons](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2013/07/things-that-java-got-right.html) that I like Java as a professional are not really applicable to education. Personally, I think MIT took the right path by using Python for their 6.01 class (replacing Scheme). But unless you can convince your superiors to change, you're stuck. And in the US, at least, Java is the language of the advanced placement test, so there's a strong barrier to change.

Comment: My first inclination was to say, "Don't." (MIT went from LISP to Python, Java has jobs, but Python jobs are growing.)

You're not going to be able to get around the basics of teaching the core Java language (the math, built-in functions, io, etc.) *But* I think it would suit your sensibilities to have them use Java to reimplement the Python built-ins, and then have them use Java and http://www.jython.org/. Then they can say they programmed in both, which might earn you even greater respect as a multi-lingual instructor.

Comment: Well, I will have to, because of centralized final exams ("Zentralabitur") that uses Java. Thanks for all comments, especially MikePartridge and @kdgregory.

Comment: Here is a (very respected) computing education researcher's voice on the matter: http://computinged.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/improve-computing-education-take-the-more-than-java-pledge/

Comment: We all feel a little discust at something new. Personally all dynamically typed languages (and that includes python) discust me a little because they are missing all the verbosity that is actually checks and ballances catching my mistakes as I make them. Write something **big** in java and it will all make sense, it feels only a little harder than writing something small. Whereas other languages start off easy and get exponentially harder as the program gets bigger

Comment: Google [scholar] Michael Kölling

Answer (score 3):

The usual reasons for teaching Java are:

- Object Oriented Design
- Cross-platform development
- Popularity

As a long time programmer, and former Java Developer, I've grown to hate Java. I was taught it in college (like everyone else), and I left college and went straight into Java development. Over time though, I was given more leeway on what platforms I could develop on, and I moved away from Java with some relief.

It's slow to develop in, it doesn't result in notably less buggy code, it doesn't result in faster code, and it doesn't result in better designed or more readable code. On top of that Oracle is more than a little evil, and I'd be more than a little leery of wedding myself to a technology they control.

Still, knowing Java will get you a job. The shit's everywhere.

Comment: "It's slow to develop in, it doesn't result in notably less buggy code, it doesn't result in faster code [...]" - compared to what?

Answer (score 2):

I think java is a great language for education purposes because it teaches some very important computer science / software engineering concepts such as

1. strong typing - the most important of all. For those who are learning, I think this is the most important thing in a language. Students don't have to struggle trying to guess what's the return type.
2. OO - Java has many influences from Eiffel and C++, it was being designed having OO concepts from the scratch (main() is a method from a class)
3. I18n - it may be seem silly, but I think it's one less barrier to learn a language
4. JVM - another thing that may be silly, but again, one less barrier to learn a language. No core dumps. You can always (almost always) get a reasonable error message. The same for garbage collection.
5. Distributed / Parallel - Java had some nice features about serialization and, in the newer versions, some very very nice features for algorithm parallelization
6. Last but not least, lots of free industrial-strength IDEs and libraries around there.

Comment: hm, I can see where my question is going... @1: Duck typing is one of my most favorite features of python, but we are really going opinion based here :(

Comment: @Jasper "Duck typing" can be achieved in statically-typed languages with more powerful type and module systems, like Standard ML. It's called *structural subtyping* there, but the concept is the same - you can use anything that satisfies a certain set of requirements. The difference is you can turn runtime errors into compile time errors.

Comment: @Jasper this is why more than one language exists. Your idea of "a nice feature" is my idea of "hellish chaos". Although my more reasonable compromise (which I don't really believe) is that "scripting style" dynamically typed languages are most appropriate for small or temporary programs and statically typed languages are more appropriate for large projects (because you can more easily break them up in your head and trust the rest of the program to follow their method signatures)